# Does AWS Lex use AWS Transcribe as the ASR for prompt recognition?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lex, amazon-transcribe

I am trying to determine if AWS Lex uses AWS Transcribe for prompt confirmations.  For example, Lex asks "What's your phone number?", the user responds with "1-2-3-4".  Lex then asks, "Did you say 1-2-3-4?".  What does Lex use behind the scenes as an ASR to determine the user said "1-2-3-4"?  Is it AWS Transcribe or something different?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think anyone knows besides AWS but it does make sense for Lex to use the power behind `AWS Transcribe` (and `AWS Polly` for returning speech from Lex). Speaking for personal experience, till about a month before Transcribe was announced at reInvent 17, I was using `Lex` to perform STT (speech to text). This was then possible as `intents` could be *ignored* & passed on to the `Lambda` handler. The JSON packet given to `Lambda` handler contained the recognized speech (as text), and I returned that back to the caller. However, sometime after they announced `Transcribe`, this stopped working, as in the `intents` could no longer be *ignored*. Any input besides those in `intents` would return the configured error response. My guess is they stopped this as they launched Transcribe.

Addendum: `AWS Transcribe` is pure ASR (auto speech recognition or speech to text). It returns the recognized speech, and meta-data (confidence etc.).

With `AWS Lex` you can design your own bots to auto-respond to queries (like in Alexa)